# Serve static content for an RoR app using .htaccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, file-upload, shared-hosting

How can I give users the ability to upload their content to my RoR application but then subsequent access to such static content that would be:

1. served by APACHE web server [to avoid the overhead of going via Rails], but
2. still want to have an authentication/authorization check to occur before they can access the content

The constraint is I'm on [DreamHost](http://dreamhost.com/) shared platform where I have only access to the Apache [`.htaccess`](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216456227--htaccess-overview) file and I can't add my own Apache modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a redirect to static content, like

```
class ImagesController
  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    if user_has_access_to @image
      redirect_to @image.bizarre_and_secret_image_location_that_is_served_by_apache
    else
      access_denied
    end
  end
end
```

It doesn't protect content completely, sure. Maybe making the static URLs temporary will help:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/RANDOMIZED_PREFIX_HERE/(.+)$ images/SECRET_IMAGE_LOCATION/$1 [L]
```

...now change the `.htaccess` file each hour. Of course the application should know the prefix, too.

Comment: Thanks but I do need proper security on the item.  So it's really more about how I could programatixally, when a user registers, to arrange that apache could serve atactic content, but based on their credentials in the app

Also would like atactic HTML pages themselves to be in scope